# Integral Operator with Discontinuous Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Deﬁne $T : C[0,\infty)\to C[0,\infty)$ by $Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(y) dy$. Show that T is an integral operator, although with a discontinuous kernel k.

I'm not really sure where to start on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can write here what is your definition of integral operator.

Comment: My definition of an integral operator is, for kernel k(x,y), $Tf(x) = \int\ k(x,y)f(y)dy$ from a to b.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(Tf)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty k(x, y) f(y) dy,
$$
where
$$
k(x, y) = 1_{(0, x)}(y)
$$
and
$$
1_{(0, x)} := \begin{cases}
1 & x \in (0,1) \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
is the indicator function.

This is because
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty k(x, y) f(y) dy = \int_{\mathbb R} 1_{(0, x)}(y) f(y) dy = \int_{(0, x)} 1_{(0, x)}(y) f(y) dy + \int_{\mathbb R \setminus (0, x)} 1_{(0, x)}(y) f(y) dy = \int_{(0, x)} 1_{(0, x)}(y) f(y) dy = \int_{(0, x)} f(y) dy = \int_0^x f(y) dy.
$$

Comment: Could you explain your answer please?

Comment: Note that  $k$ is the characteristic function of the set $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:\; 0\leq y\leq x\}.$$

Comment: Note that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx := \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$.